# How to use promise function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.editData = function(newValue){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         $scope.Data=newValue;
         deferred.resolve($scope.Data);
         return deferred.promise;
    };
```

I have written this function in starting point of the controller,i have used promise for this function only,because when the data is assinged to the variable **$scope.Data** then only remaining part of the functions should proceed in the controller.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share the controller code too where you have implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not beneficial at all, it will act like sync code.
Change it like this:

```
$scope.editData = function(newValue){
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         $timeout(function() {
             $scope.Data=newValue;
             deferred.resolve($scope.Data);
             return deferred.promise;
         },50);

         return deferred.promise;
    };
```

This way you gonna let the code continue executing and after 50 milliseconds, the promise will be resolved.
This is how you use the function `editData`:

```
$scope.editData(newValue).then(function() { /* do something here */ });
```